# How to add styles to an unknown child in React with Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

The below function is going to be run on a loop. I want to add styles to the `icon` which I want to pass as an argument to the function.

The `icon` is a going to be an unknown React Material-UI  Icon component.

```js
const renderStyledCard = (lightMode, heading, num, icon) => {
  const classes = lightMode ? useLightCardStyles(): useDarkCardStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h4" className={classes.textColor}>
          {heading}
        </Typography>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <Typography variant="h4" component="h4" className={classes.textColor}>
            {num}
          </Typography>
          {icon}
          // Ex. <VpnKey className={[classes.icon, classes.textColor]} />
          // Ex. <AccountCircle className={[classes.icon, classes.textColor]} />
          {icon}
        </div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Loop execution is going to be like -

```js
return [
        {light: true, 
         heading: 'Accounts', 
         num: 100, 
         icon: <AccountCircle />
        },
        ...theRest
       ].map(ele => renderStyledCard(...ele))
```

The loop code could be wrong I just wrote it here as an example to show how I wanted to execute it. Is there a better way? Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notice points:

- add `{}` like `({ light, heading, num, icon })` to list the props
- props `lightMode` not match list attribute `light`, need to change one of them
- use Material-UI [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) `& svg` to customize the icon style from its parent div

---

Full code sample:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import GetApp from "@material-ui/icons/GetApp";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import { Card, CardContent, Typography, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
const useLightCardStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {},
  content: {
    "& svg": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
}));
const useDarkCardStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({}));

const data = [
  { light: true, heading: "Accounts", num: 100, icon: <AccountCircle /> },
  { light: true, heading: "Accounts", num: 100, icon: <GetApp /> }
];

const StyledCard = ({ light, heading, num, icon }) => {
  const lightCardClasses = useLightCardStyles();
  const darkCardClasses = useDarkCardStyles();
  const classes = light ? lightCardClasses : darkCardClasses;
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h4" className={classes.textColor}>
          {heading}
        </Typography>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <Typography variant="h4" component="h4" className={classes.textColor}>
            {num}
          </Typography>
          {icon}
        </div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(props => (
        <StyledCard {...props} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit jovial-bassi-oolrk]

[image]

Comment: Thank you  @keikai. Your solution is working temporarily. React then fails to compile it and throws an error. The app just renders for a second and then it crashes to the error.
`Line 40:  React Hook "useLightCardStyles" is called in function "renderStyledCard" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`. In your sandbox demo it shows as a warning. I'm using React `v16.9.0`.

Comment: @AyushNair I simply forked your code, now it's been fixed. There are other issues but I guess it's not related to the problem you described in this post.

Comment: @keikai This still has conditional hook usage (useLightCardStyles() is used conditionally). Here's an example that fixes it: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-bassi-oolrk

Comment: @RyanCogswell thank you so much. Both of you. It's working now without any warnings or errors. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
const renderStyledCard = (lightMode, heading, num, icon) => {
  const classes = lightMode ? useLightCardStyles(): useDarkCardStyles();
  icon.style.color = "red";
  return(/*....*/)
}
```

Try `console.log(icon.style)`